# Facing issues while fetching data from two different mysql tables using a single query..!

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one for the posts and another for the users. I am fetching all posts from the 'posts' table and user data (who posted that post) from the tbl_users.

currently, I am using this query :

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `posts`,`tbl_users` WHERE id = user_id_p ORDER BY `post_id` DESC");
            $query->execute();
            return $query->fetchAll();
```

it is working fine, it is fetching all the posts from the posts table and user data from tbl_users.
However, my issue is this that I don't want to fetch all posts, but I want to fetch only those posts which are posted by the specific user(for example by John only) and the user data for John only from the tbl_user.

(field Id from tbl_users and field user_id_p from the table posts are same in both the tables.)

Any suggestions or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your query *is working*, it is not at all efficient because it uses an implicit [cross join](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php) which results in a very large resultset.
Use a proper [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) with a condition applied with `WHERE`:

```
SELECT u.*, p.* 
FROM tbl_users u INNER JOIN posts p
ON u.id = p.user_id_p
WHERE u.id = ?
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC
```

Replace `?` with the id of the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` for this. Example

```
select P.name, U.name from post P NATURAL JOIN user U;
```